# Randomly chosen from a set of $3$-digit

Tags: probability, statistics

If $n$ is chosen randomly from the set of $3$-digit positive integers with no odd digits, what is the probability that n has no repeated digits? The answers is $48\%$.

What I did is find the total possibilities of even digits $(2,4,6,8)= 4!=24$ and than find the $3$-digit combo out of those even numbers that has no repeat. But I didn't get the right answer.

Please help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: 0 is also even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $n$ is a random $3$-digit positive integer with no odd digits. To find the probability that there are no repeated digits, we must find the number of possible values of $n$ that have no repeated digits and divide it by the total number of possible values of $n$. First we will do the latter of the two.

For the first digit, there are $4$ options for digits (since $0$ cannot be the first digit) and there are $5$ for both the second and third. Thus the number of possible values of $n$ is
$$4\cdot5\cdot5$$
$$100$$
Now we must find the number with no repeated digits. In this case, there would be $4$ options for the first digit (if we pick it first), then $4$ for the second (if we pick it next), and then only $3$ for the last digit (if we pick it last). Thus the number of possible values of $n$ with no repeated digits is
$$4\cdot4\cdot3$$
$$48$$
So the probability is
$$\frac{48}{100}$$

Answer (score 1):

Choose the digits one by one and start with the utmost left.

The probability that the second digit differs from the first is $\frac45$.

Under the condition that this occurs the probability that the third digit differs from the first an second is $\frac35$.

Multiplication of these probabilities gives you the answer:$$\frac45\frac35=\frac{12}{25}=\frac{48}{100}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint. The $3$ even distinct digits (with no initial zero) can be chosen in $4\cdot 4\cdot 3$ ways. On the other hand, $3$ even digits (not necessarily distinct with no initial zero) can be chosen in $4\cdot 5\cdot 5$ ways.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: That is incorrect. Zero should not be an option for the first digit, so it should instead by $4\cdot4\cdot3$

Comment: @Nilknarf Thanks, I misread the question.